# Pandas - Get Series index during vectorized operation

Tags: python, pandas

Say, I have a dataframe df where one of the columns is:

```
df['letters'] = pd.Series(['a','a','m','a'])
```

and I want to add a message column to the df, like below:
(if something like index() existed, would be nice.)

```
message_col = np.where(df['letters']=='a','found','missing at index'+str(df['letters'].index()))
```

The result would be:

```
df['message_col'] = pd.Series(['found','found','missing at index 2','found'])
```

Comment: it does, just not a method: `df.letters.index`.

Comment: Change your np.where to `np.where(df['letters'] == 'a', 'found', 'missing at index' + df['letters'].index.astype(str))
`